# postfix configuration for user-xxx@domain

Tags: postfix

### I'm trying to configure postfix to allow user x @ mydomain.yyy to accept email to any address of the form x[-.*]@mydomain.yyy
so x@mydomain.yyy, x-abc@mydomain.yyy, x-lame@mydomain.yyy, ....

What i have is a file regex-rewrite with:

```
/^xxx@mydomain.yyy$/ OK
/^xxx[-][^@]@mydomain.yyy$/ OK
/^[^@]*mydomain.yyy$/ 500 NO UCE
```

---

and i have the proconf variable smtpd_recipient_restrictions= "... regex:/etc/postfix/recip-re"

but alas it does not work and i dont' see how to trace the output of the regex rewrite rule to see where i went horribly wrong.

Comment: Here is more information: postmap -q 'xxx-x@my domain.yyy' regexp/etc/postfix/recip-re returns ok but postmap -q 'xxxx@mydomain.yyy' ... returns 500 but both deliver the mail.